# What Django model field should I use for WYSIWYG data from React?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-models

I am creating a blog application and want to use a text editor/ WYSIWYG editor for individual posts. Since I will be using React for the frontend, the data will be received through an API (using DRF for that). So in my model, what field should I create that will accept the WYSIWYG  data?

eg. model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
```

I want the `content` field to be accepting that data

Comment: TextField is fine why do you want to change

Comment: I don't want to change. I just want to know what would be the correct field. So i guess textfield is ok. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably if your WYSIWYG editor is actually creating html files, and at this time not handling the inserted files (images), the TextField should be enough. It is additional issue if you enable pictures or other multimedia elements to be inserted while editing, but they would have to be dealt separately.

So, for general html files, produced by your WYSIWYG editor plain TextField should be enough.

Comment: And what if i do want to handle images?

Comment: It really depends on your frontend and how you will post images to image storage. Unfortunately I don't know React that much to be able to help you here, but I presume that you would need to send through DRF image names (together with everything else) and then upload images in separate post to Django server. Please be aware that it might be available some other idea, but as I said not a React master myself.